# I cant get swagger to run on https

Tags: c#, swagger

I've come on board to work on an existing project written in .net framework 4.5.2.
We have a whole host of APi Controllers and we will be extending these. I have used Nuget Package manager and installed the Swashbuckle.Net45 v5.2.1 package. This also generated my basic swaggerconfig.cs file. We run our app using https. When I add swagger to my url I get the swagger UI showing, but no api's, instead a red box to the right with Error. When I open the error, I receive the following message:

> `{"schemaValidationMessages":[{"level":"error","message":"Can't read
>   from file https://ved:443/myvoucher/swagger/docs/v1"}]}'

Comment: Try this and let me know if it works: `config.EnableSwagger().EnableSwaggerUi(c => c.DisableValidator());`

Comment: @SalahAkbari This removes the redbox error that I get on the swagger home page, but I dont see any of the controller API's